# Codeship ssh commands

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, codeship

According to the documentation (https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/#run-commands-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh), you need to run all commands as a single command.

While I understand that, I don't understand how I can run the following as a single command, the process would be:

1. ssh demo@111.1.111.101
2. ssh user@test-server
3. cd deploy
4. ./deploy.sh

Not that the second command is run on `111.1.111.101` as `demo`

This is currently what I've tried:

`ssh demo@111.1.111.101 "ssh user@test-server; cd deploy; ./deploy.sh"`

But this seems to get stuck after the first ssh command, it never goes to the second ssh.

Comment: hey, can you explain why it's necessary for you to have two layers of ssh? and on what machine is the `deploy/deploy.sh` script located?

Comment: It's just the way our server is setup at the moment, I can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh -t demo@111.1.111.101 'ssh user@test-server "cd deploy; ./deploy.sh"'
```

Comment: This is perfect, works exactly as expected. Didn't know you could mix up the single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Like user156213 said probably you dont need two jumps, but anyway you are adding a ; after the ssh that breaks everything

With one jump

```
ssh user@test-server "cd deploy ; ./deploy.sh"
```

also you can try to remove the first line

```
ssh user@test-server ./deploy/deploy.sh
```

Take a look at ProxyCommand in ssh to avoid the jumps, edit your .ssh/config to include something like that

```
Host first
  Hostname 111.1.111.101
  User demo

Host second 
  User user
  ProxyCommand ssh -q first nc test-server
```

Now with a simple

```
ssh second deploy/deploy.sh
```

will do the work

Comment: Sadly I do need the two layers of ssh, I can't change that, so I need to figure out how to do it with one single command.

Comment: With the ProxyCommand configuration you can do the two layers of ssh just in one, also allows you to use more complex commands based on ssh like rsync or git. By example a rsync -av /tmp/ second:/tmp/ will rsync your local /tmp with the remote one jumping through the first ssh proxy

Comment: That makes sense, but I didn't have much configuration options over that server and had to work with the simple commands I was given.